# Custom Subview of ViewGroup isn't showing up. How do I add custom views to a class extending ViewGroup?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, mobile-application

I'm trying to create a small BrickBreaker game.

I have a MainActivity.java, BrickBreakerView.java, and a Paddle.java so far. BrickBreakerView extends the ViewGroup class, and Paddle extends the View class. I'm hoping to be able to add a Paddle, Bricks, Ball, and a Scoreboard (custom view classes that I will create) to the BrickBreakerView. Essentially, BrickBreakerView will control the interactions of these views.

The MainActivity's xml layout adds a BrickBreakerView to the layout. The BrickBreakerView instantiates a Paddle in the onCreate method, and it also adds the paddle as a subview (addView()).

I've overwritten the Paddle's onDraw method to draw a blue rectangle given X and Y positions. However, when I run my program, I don't see anything on screen. I have tested with Log.d to check that the BrickBreakerView's and Paddle's constructors ARE being called.

Thanks for any help! Also, I am new to Android development, and if you guys could give me some comments regarding the structure of my game, I would be grateful :D!

Here are the relevant pieces of code.

This is called in my main activity:

```
 setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

My main.xml looks like:
     .BrickBreakerView

```
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

The BrickBreakerView.java class:

```
 public class BrickBreakerView extends ViewGroup{

public BrickBreakerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
    Paddle paddle = new Paddle(context, 100, 400);
    paddle.setYPosition(400);
    addView(paddle);
    Log.d("print", "Brick Breaker View constructor");
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("print", "onLayout called");
}
```

}

The Paddle.java class:

```
 public class Paddle extends View{

private int myX, myY;

public Paddle(Context context, int xPos, int yPos) {
    super(context);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    Log.d("print", "paddle constructor");
    myX = xPos;
    myY = yPos;
    invalidate();
}
public void setXPosition(int x) {
    myX = x;
    invalidate();
}
public void setYPosition(int y) {
    myY = y;
    invalidate();
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.d("print", "onDraw called");
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawRect(myX, myY, myX+100, myY+50, paint);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Make the paddle instance a member var of brick breaker view. 
Create and add it to the view group - you are doing this. 
In onLayout, put paddle.layout(0,0,100,100)